# swift server side server socket error

Tags: swift, vapor, perfect

I'm suffering from server problem on both **perfect and vapor** ..

The server working for **only one time** , and once after i update the project and rebuild it, the server response does not update any more.

I got this error ... from vapor in Xcode

```
No command supplied, defaulting to serve...
Starting server on 0.0.0.0:8080
Serve error: Sockets Error: Failed trying to bind to the address

Identifier: Sockets.SocketsError.bindFailed
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I googled alot , but did not figure out the problem

Finally : when i restart the mac , the server worked good only for one time , and the problem returned the same .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved after 2 days of searching by removing Xcode and reinstalling it .. Although Xcode was working well and i have just installed it one month before , but after i tested everything i tried hopelessly to do that and it worked .. seems frustrating , but it worth mentioning that for anyone who would facing that thing .

Answer (score 14):

Seems like a process is using port 8080. Try running `lsof -i :8080` from the terminal and kill it's PID with `kill -9 PID`